# Subviews are not shown after return from dismiss "mainTabBar" view

Tags: iphone, uiview, keyboard

I have a UIView (superview) with two sub views (1.UIScrollView and 2.UIView), the first view is a login form, and the second view contains a launch animation (with a UIImageView). When the animation finish, I remove it from superview, then, after the login is validated, it presents a new TabBarViewController, wich has a Home and other navigation controllers. Home navigation controller has a logout button, the action of logout is called method "logout" in tabBarViewController and such method dismisses itself to back login form.

```
@implementation LoginViewController

MainTabBarViewController *mainTabBarViewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBarViewController"];

[self presentViewController: mainTabBarViewController animated: YES completition: nil];

Logout works fine as long as the keyboard is never shown, otherwise the login form doesn´t appear, the superview does.

@implementation MainTabBarViewController

-(void)logout{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completition: nil];

}
```

I notice that loginView (1.ScrollView) is in the top of the stack and hidden property is NO.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

NOTE: I use ARC, storyboard and iOS 5

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in my loginView I adjust the frame in UIScrollView to move to visible area the TextField when keyboard appears, I did this registering keyboard notifications, so, when the keyboard appeared somewhere, the loginView fall into one invisible area, so the solution was register keyboard notificacion when loginView appear and unregister when disappear.

Thank you, and sorry about my english!!